# Refer ranges in a closed workbook with dynamic file path, INDEX(MATCH())

Tags: excel, vba, range, user-defined-functions, excel-indirect

I'm using the Index(Match()) function to lookup a value from another closed workbook. The formula within cell `B5` of the currently opened workbook is:

```
=INDEX('C:\Users\Downloads\[og.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$3,MATCH($A$5,'C:\Users\Downloads\[og.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$3,0))
```

where `$A$5` stores the lookup value.

The path of source file `C:\Users\Downloads\[og.xlsx]Sheet1` will change dynamically, and it is stored in the current workbook in cell `C1` as text string without `'` at either ends. **I would like to have some help writing a user defined function** (not sub!) in vba to replace the fomula as:

```
=INDEX(getValue($C$1,"$B$1:$B$3"),MATCH($A$5,getValue($C$1,"$A$1:$A$3"),0))
```

**NOTE:**

1. The source file should not open at any point, so `INDIRECT()` won't work.
2. Excel add-in is not preferred, so no `INDIRECT.EXT()`.
3. The `getValue(path,range)` function should also work when `range` refers to a single cell value. (i.e. `=getValue($C$1,"$B$1")` should work as a cell formula alone)
4. I noticed the post [Use file path from a predefined cell in a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072781/use-file-path-from-a-predefined-cell-in-a-formula) , which works fine for single cell value but not range when using index(match()). Also, I tried the following which returns `#VALUE!`:

```
    Function GetValue(Rpath As String, Rrange As String)
        Dim a, strRef As String
        a = range(Rrange).Address(, , xlR1C1)
        strRef = "'" & Rpath & "'!" & a
        GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(strRef)
    End Function
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you have a question? You've posted requirements, but no code and no question

Comment: my question is how to write such a function? so far i tried `ExecuteExcel4Macro`, but it only works in sub(), not function().

Comment: Post your code and explain where you are stuck. Why would you use ExcecuteExcel4Macro if you use VBA?

Comment: [This seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521245/a-function-within-a-function-in-vba).

Comment: thx, but the fix only works for single-cell reference, not for the range which is used in the index match function.